# Meaning of the color highlighting in personal Wikipedia articles

Tags: wikipedia

In the articles about people I noticed that some names have different highlighting. Googling give me a lot of nonsense Wiki articles about colors. What does the color mean around names?

[image: Jake Sinclair article]

[image: Andrew McMahon article]

Answer (score 2):

The colours are decided on what kind of artist they have been labeled as in their infobox. Jake Sinclair has been tagged as `non_vocal_instrumentalist` whereas Andrew McMahon is tagged `solo_singer`.
Read more about it on the documentation page of the [Infobox musical artist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_musical_artist#background)